# Why doesn't SpringApplication terminate immediately after it starts?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Here is a typical SpringApplication instance:

```
public class MyService {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(MyService.class);
        ApplicationContext ctx = app.run(args);
    }
}
```

Since `app.run(args)` is a non-blocking call, the `main` method of this application returns immediately after its invocation. I have always thought that an application terminates when you return from `main`.

Why does `SpringApplication` continue run even though we have returned out of `main`?

Comment: Please post a real example. That code exits as soon as `run` returns (assuming it doesn't fail because it's set with a web environment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JVM terminates [when the last non-daemon thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon(boolean)) finishes. It seems that your application is creating thread(s) that do not terminate.

On Unix, you can find out what is the state of your threads by sending signal 3 (`kill -3 <java-pid>`) to [get a thread dump](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/18178) on output. That could tell you more.